# ¿Como puedo colocar la suma de los numeros pares en el lugar del mayor numero impar de un arreglo bidimensional en NetBeans?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> 3. Ingresar números enteros a una matriz de N filas con M columnas, calcular la suma de los números pares de la matriz, luego de los números impares hallar el mayor número y colocar la suma en el lugar del mayor número impar.
>    package Vectores;

Explicare lo que avance: Según el ejercicio 3 que me piden, hice como módulos en NetBeans lo siguiente:

```
//este creo que es el modulo con lo que trabaja este ejercicio

//Primer main class

package Vectores;//El nombre del paquete 

//Libreria

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //que es para no nos muestre ningun error algo asi

public class Proceso {//Le puse Proceso para no confundirme

//Esta es la funcion que lee un numero entero y retorna el numero

public static int LeerNumero(String mensaje){

    int num;//Esta es su variable

    num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mensaje));

    return num;

}

//esta es la funcion que lee los datos de vector de numeros y retorna el vector

public static int[] LeerVectorNumero(int N){

    int[] num =  new int[N];
    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        num[i] = LeerNumero("Ingrese dato para la posicion "+i);
    }
    return num;
}

//este es el procedimiento que realiza las impresiones en pantalla

public static void ImprimirMensaje(String mensaje){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mensaje);

}     
}//Fin class

//hasta aqui termine con esa parte que me ayudara a leer los valores en el siguiente main class 

//Segundo main class

package arreglo_bidimensional_2;

//Libreria

import Vectores.Proceso; //como en el anterior main class puse Vectores segun el paquete donde estan los procesos, puse tambien el nombre del primer public class

public class Arreglo_Bidimensional_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

  //Aqui coloque las variables del arreglo bidimensional para definir las filas y columnas...la suma de pares y para hallar el mayor numero impar.

        int matriz[][],N,M,mayorI=-99999;
        int SumaPar=0;
 //lectura de la dimensiones de la matriz

//Como N y M van a reprensentar el arreglo, los coloque mas la funcion del primer paquete que leera los numeros enteros y los retornara
 
      N = Proceso.LeerNumero("Ingrese el tamaño de filas de la matriz : ");
      M = Proceso.LeerNumero("Ingrese el tamaño de columnas de la matriz : ");

      //creando la matriz con las dimensiones

      matriz = new int[N][M];

      //Lectura de los datos de la Matriz

      for(int i=0 ;i<N ; i++){      //recorrido por filas segun el tamaño de la N
          for(int j=0; j<M ; j++){  //recorrido por columnas segun el tamaño de la M
            matriz[i][j] = Proceso.LeerNumero("Ingrese el valor para la matriz["+i+"]["+j+"] = ");
//Aqui es donde se va colocar lo datos en sus respectivas posiciones segun el numero que se escriba en la matriz

          }          
      }

      //calculos
      for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M ; j++){

            if(matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0)//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros pares
                SumaPar = SumaPar+ matriz[i][j];//segun los datos de la matriz se suman todos los numeros pares existentes de la matriz

            if(matriz[i][j]%2!= 0)//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros impares
                if(matriz[i][j]>mayorI){//segun la condicion se obtiene el mayor numero impar
                mayorI = matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
      }
      //Generando la cadena de los datos de la matriz para la impresión
      //Aqui no se que explicar :'(

      String cadena="";
      for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
      for(int j=0 ; j<M ;j++){
              if(j!=(M-1))  cadena = cadena + matriz[i][j]+" - ";//esto creo que es para demostrar los datos la matriz de la primera columna

              else cadena = cadena + matriz[i][j];//al igual que este pero este creo que muestra las demas columnas
              
          }
          cadena =  cadena + "\n";//la cadena mostrara todos los datos del arreglos
      }
      
      //Mostrando los resultados
//Como en el anterior su funcion nos ayudara a mostrar los resultados como si fuera el null creo

      Proceso.ImprimirMensaje("Los datos de la matriz son : \n"+cadena+
              "\nLa suma de los numeros pares es    : "+SumaPar+
              "\nEl mayor número impar es           : "+mayorI);
               
      }//Fin void     
}//Fin class
```

Espero que esto les ayude a entender el ejercicio, ya que hasta ahí me muestra la suma de los números pares y el numero mayor impar, pero quiero que salga otro mensaje que me muestre los datos de la matriz bidimensional, pero en vez del numero mayor impar salga la suma de los números.

Según mi error que cometí, después de tratar de hacer una cadena para que me muestre el segundo mensaje pero en vez del numero impar mayor, es remplazado por la suma de los pares, eso lo hice después de la primera muestra de los resultados.

Me muestra así:

Ejemplo:

Matriz 2x2, numeros 1-5,2-4

> 1-5
> 2-4

6, este es la suma de los pares pero no remplaza el mayor numero impar que es 5 a parte siempre se que en esa posición como la del 2, ¿que debería corregir?

Adjunto una imagen para que me expliquen en que me equivoque:

[image: En esta imagen que debo corregir para que me imprima el segundo mensaje sin errores]

En esta imagen que debo corregir para que me imprima el segundo mensaje sin errores

---

En esta segunda imagen que me falta completar, o en que me equivoque porque solo me imprime la matriz pero sin remplazar el numero impar mayor por la suma de los pares.

[image: En la segunda imagen que me falta completar o en que me equivoque porque solo me imprime la matriz pero sin remplazar el numero impar mayor por la suma de los pares]

[image: Que error hubo aqui?, me sigue mostrando lo mismo pero no remplazo el mayor numero impar por la suma de los numeros pares.]

[image: En la cuarta imagen me muestra el primer mensaje pero el numero impar ya es reemplazado, pero en este mensaje no se debe modificar el arreglo]

[image: Este es el segundo mensaje que es ahi donde se debe modificar el numero impar mayor por la suma a pesar que se repitan, pero solo reemplazo a uno]

[image: Cual fue el error?]

Comment: Podrías haber editado la pregunta que ya habías creado. Ahora, lo más probable es que cierren una de tus dos preguntas si no lo haces tú antes.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estas guardando el índice donde se encuentra el mayor número impar, para ello reemplaza el fragmento de tu código

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M ; j++){

            if(matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0)//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros pares
                SumaPar = SumaPar+ matriz[i][j];//segun los datos de la matriz se suman todos los numeros pares existentes de la matriz

            if(matriz[i][j]%2!= 0)//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros impares
                if(matriz[i][j]>mayorI){//segun la condicion se obtiene el mayor numero impar
                mayorI = matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
      }
```

Por el siguiente código

```
int fila=0,columna=0;//para guardar el índice del mayor número impar
      //calculos
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M ; j++){

            if(matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0)//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros pares
                SumaPar = SumaPar+ matriz[i][j];//segun los datos de la matriz se suman todos los numeros pares existentes de la matriz

            else {//este es una condicion para hallar los numeros impares
                if(matriz[i][j]>mayorI){//segun la condicion se obtiene el mayor numero impar
                    mayorI = matriz[i][j];
                    fila=i;
                    columna=j;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
      
    matriz[fila][columna]=SumaPar;//cambiamos el valor de mayor valor impar por la suma de los pares
```

Comment: Termina el bucle y cambia el numero mayor impar por la suma de los números pares? Si la matriz tiene mucho mas números y el numero mayor impar se repite solo cambiara uno de ellos, el que haya quedado guardado en el indice por ultimo lugar. Por eso primero calculamos cual es el mayor y luego mientras iteramos el arreglo comprobamos si el numero actual es igual al mayor impar, si se repiten de igual modo se cambiara por el mayor impar, como mostré en mi primer ejemplo los 41 se remplazaban por 34 que era la suma de todos los pares.

Comment: Sólo hice para el caso de tu ejemplo en el cual sólo 1 elemento de tu matriz sea el mayor número impar; si tienes en mente insertar en tu matriz varios números impares que sean mayores, entonces ya solución es fácil; en vez de crear 2 variables que almacenen el índice del elemento impar mayor, crea 2 vectores que vayan guardando los índices de cada elemento mayor y cuando reemplazas la suma de los pares en la matriz que sea para elemento de los vectores que haz creado. Haz el intento y si no te sale edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Hasta ahi okay, pero como dice JFrame los numero impares mayores  que se repiten, solo uno de ellos se cambia, a parte cuando reemplaze ese fragmento como indicaste, normal me reemplaza el numero impar mayor pero solo a uno en caso que se repiten, y como mi matriz me muestra 2 mensajes, en el primer y segundo mensaje me muestran el mismo arreglo, pero yo solo quiero que en el primer mensaje me muestre el arreglo sin modificar y en el segundo ya modificado (osea que el numero impar ya fue reemplazado con la suma de los pares). Ahora subo las imagenes para mostrarte.

Comment: Ahora como puedes visualizar la cuarta y quinta imagen, que se deberia corregir en este caso?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar la matriz antes y después del cambio ya lo tienes todo hecho, primero muestra la matriz ingresado, luego realiza el cambio de los valores mayores por la suma de pares y por ultimo vuelve a mostrar la matriz cambiado, todo en ese orden